# fancyhdr: include footnote only on page 1, but header on all pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to put a footer on page 1 but not on other pages. I also want to put a header on all pages. Could some one tell me how I can do that?
The code I am using so far (only relevant lines shown):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is my header text}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{This is my footer text}
```

This generates a header on all pages (which is good), but also a footer on all pages. I don't want footer on pages other than the first.

Comment: Actually I don't know the extent of my _titlepage_. It is a conference paper and so there is no _titlepage_.

Comment: Oh cool! That worked! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this MWE, it shoud do it for you:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78349/fancyhdr-include-footnote-only-on-page-1-but-header-on-all-pages
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is my header text}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Test Paper}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

%following page with footer
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{This is my footer text}
\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\lfoot{}       % this was missing!
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```